# How to remove duplicate list in List<List<int>>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, equality

I have `List<List<int>>`, For example
`List<List<int>>` has `{{1,2,3}, {1,1,2,}, {1,2,3}}`.

I want to remove duplicate in this:
Result should be: `{{1,2,3}, {1,1,2}}`

The problem is the inner lists are reference types so they have different object hashcode and hence are treated separate.

I don't want to iterate list completely to find duplicates as its not optimum.

Comment: I don't get the last sentence. In the end you just have too look at every element (whether that is "hidden" behind some LINQ code or explicit).

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
List<List<int>> lst = new List<List<int>>()
{
    new List<int> {1,2,3},
    new List<int> {1,1,2}, 
    new List<int> {1,2,3}
};

var result = lst.GroupBy(c => String.Join(",", c)).Select(c => c.First().ToList()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can implement an `EqualityComparer` class and use it in `Distinct` method of LINQ.

```
public class CustomEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<List<int>>
{
     public bool Equals(List<int> x, List<int> y)
     {
         if (x.Count != y.Count)
             return false;
         for (int i = 0; i < x.Count; i++)
         {
            if (x[i] != y[i])
                return false;
         }
         return true;
     }

     public int GetHashCode(List<int> obj)
     {
         return 0;
     }
}
```

and use it like this

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = new List<List<int>>() { new List<int> { 1, 1, 2 }, new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }, new List<int> { 1, 1, 2 } };
    var res = list.Distinct(new CustomEqualityComparer());
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: If you don't known the count of the collection ie whether it's always very small, then you should implement `GetHashCode`. It is utilized by the `Distinct` method.

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple:

```
List<List<int>> lst = new List<List<int>>()
{
    new List<int> {1,2,3},
    new List<int> {1,1,2,}, 
    new List<int> {1,2,3},
};

var result =
    lst
        .Where((xs, n) =>
            !lst
                .Skip(n + 1)
                .Any(ys => xs.SequenceEqual(ys)))
        .ToList();
```

I get this result:

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

What you want is more complicated than simple comparision.
In my point of view you should create a new type / class like
IntegerCollection : ICollection

Then you should implement Equals in that way:

```
bool Equals(IntegerCollection col) {    if(this.Count() != col.Count())
      return false;

   if(this.Sum() != col.Sum())
      return false;

   for(int i = 0; i < this.Count(); i++)    {
      if(this[i]==col[i]){
         continue;
      }else{
         return false;
      }    }

   return true; }
```

And finally

```
List<IntegerCollection> collections = new List<IntegerCollection> {
     new IntegerCollection({1,2,3}),
     new IntegerCollection({1,1,2}),
     new IntegerCollection({1,2,3})};
var distincts = collections.Distinct();
```

Comment: Some advice is in F# you have this option navite based on tuplas

Answer (score 0):

Using [@farid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31229294/2946329)'s `CustomEqualityComparer` you can also make use of `HashSet`:

```
List<List<int>> RemoveDuplicates(IEnumerable<List<int>> values)
{
    return new HashSet<List<int>>(values,new CustomEqualityComparer()).ToList();
}
```